# Edit Text Wont Bring Up Keyboard in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

I tried adding focusable mode. I looked through all the settings. I watched a bunch of tutorials and to my knowledge I am doing everything right.

When I click on the text field on the edit text. Nothing happens.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:editable="true"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="false"
        android:hint="Stuff you want to do"
        android:inputType="number|text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Try to check if the touches are being detected by simply printing any msg in the log from the editText's onclicklistner. Sometimes other views overlaps .

Answer (score 0):

Try checking in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Make sure `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myactivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
```